# Convert Word to Smallest PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, libreoffice

I am trying to convert MS Word to PDF and need help in finding the best way to create the PDF with the smallest size.  I have tried LibreOffice and the results are very good.  Foxit and DoPDF creates the smallest size PDF but loses links.

Export or Save AS from MS word creates the biggest PDF and is only marginally better looking than LibreOffice.

Are there any suggestions?

Below is a table of the results that I have:

Megs    Method of Conversion

```
  6.3    dopdf
 53.8    fox-it reader
167.0    Min Word (embedded fonts removed)
428.2    ms word
 37.9    Change to odt first (exported using LibreOffice)
 33.4    Word Doc File (original source)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/. . .

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Adobe Distiller** which is part of the Adobe Creative Suite or when you buy Adobe Acrobat. In both Acrobat and the Distiller you can set various options (e.g. to increase the compression of images) to reduce the overall file size.

The easiest way would be to use their preset, i.e. go to **Properties -> Smallest File Size** and you should be set.